# Spring SAML redirecting to a different URL

Tags: java, spring, saml-2.0, spring-saml, opensaml

I employed this [spring boot SAML sample project](https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample/blob/master/src/main/java/com/vdenotaris/spring/boot/security/saml/web/config/WebSecurityConfig.java) to my existing project. But I noticed that the redirect url will be automatically set as the url where I get redirected to the log in page. I am wondering is there anyway for me to change this redirect url to a different one? The base url that will trigger redirection to the auth page is a http link but I need to redirect to a https link after logging in. (Now I am not able to move forward to the page where I can input credentials. I am blocked by the invalid url error.) For now I tried create a custom LoginSuccessHandler that implements *AuthenticationSuccessHandler* .

```
 @Component
public class LoginSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler{

    private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        
        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response,"/testing");
    }
}
```

And I had this in the saml config

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(samlEntryPoint());
    http
            .addFilterBefore(metadataGeneratorFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
            .addFilterAfter(samlFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(samlFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().successHandler(successHandler);
    http
            .logout()
            .disable(); // The logout procedure is already handled by SAML filters.
}
```

But this doesn't work. The redirect url does't get changed to what I specified ("/testing"). While using Inteli J debugging mode, it seems that this custom class is not being executed. So I am suspecting I had the wrong way calling this class. Then I also tried provided this *LoginSuccessHandler* class to *samlWebSSOProcessingFilter*, which also made no difference.

```
@Bean
public SAMLProcessingFilter samlWebSSOProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
    SAMLProcessingFilter samlWebSSOProcessingFilter = new SAMLProcessingFilter();
    samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
    samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/spring-security-saml2-sample");
    samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successRedirectHandler());
    
    return samlWebSSOProcessingFilter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following changes to redirect to desired URL.
First inject the dependency `LoginSuccessHandler` in the `WebSecurityConfig` file

```
@Autowired
private LoginSuccessHandler loginSuccessHandler;
```

and then update the `SAMLProcessingFilter` as mentioned below

```
// Processing filter for WebSSO profile messages
@Bean
public SAMLProcessingFilter samlWebSSOProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
    SAMLProcessingFilter samlWebSSOProcessingFilter = new SAMLProcessingFilter();
    samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
    samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(loginSuccessHandler);
     samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler());
    return samlWebSSOProcessingFilter;
}
```

then do the following change in the `LoginSuccessHandler`

```
@Component
public class LoginSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // Add your server URL below.
        String redirectUri = "https://{server}/testing";
        response.sendRedirect(redirectUri);
    }

}
```